# Does the following result hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and non-negative matrices.

Let $\rho(A)$ denote the spectral radius of $A$ and $\rho(B)$ denote the spectral radius of $B$.

Does the following result hold?

> $\rho(A+B)\le \rho(A)+\rho(B)$

I tried several examples and found the result true.

But is it true in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true if $A$ and $B$ are real. For symmetric real matrices, the spectral radius agrees with the operator norm
$$
\|A\|=\max\{\|Ax\|_2:\ \|x\|_2=1\}.
$$
And the sum of real symmetric matrices is real symmetric. Thus
$$
\rho(A+B)=\|A+B\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|=\rho(A)+\rho(B). 
$$
Non-negative is not necessary for all the above.

The same result holds for complex matrices if we replace "symmetric" with "selfadjoint".

---

Another way to prove it is to use the [Min-Max Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)  (Courant-Fischer-Weyl):  if $\lambda_1\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ (and $A$ is Hermitian, so real and symmetric qualifies)
$$
\lambda_k=\min_{\dim K=k}\max_{x\in K, \|x\|=1} \langle Ax,x\rangle.
$$
When $k=n$, 
\begin{align}
\lambda_n(A+B)&=\max_{x\in K, \|x\|=1} \langle (A+B)x,x\rangle\\
&\leq \max_{x\in K, \|x\|=1} \langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle Bx,x\rangle\\
&\leq \max_{x\in K, \|x\|=1} \langle Ax,x\rangle+\max_{x\in K, \|x\|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle\\
&=\lambda_n(A)+\lambda_n(B)\\
&\leq\rho(A)+\rho(B). 
\end{align}
Since $\rho(A+B)$ is either $|\lambda_1(A+B)|$ or $|\lambda_n(A+B)|$, we get
$$
\rho(A+B)\leq \rho(A)+\rho(B). 
$$
Again, "non-negative" is not needed.

Comment: Yes they are real.But can you prove this fact "For symmetric real matrices, the spectral radius agrees with the operator norm"

Comment: Is is possible to prove this fact that $\rho(A+B)\le \rho(A)+\rho(B)$ using linear algebra without using any functional analysis techniques.Please comment

Comment: I included another argument. You would have to say what "functional analysis techniques" are.

Comment: Its clear now,thank you very much for your time & effort